# Spark Dataframe - how to access json structure

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I have a json file look like this:

```
{
  "employeeDetails":{
    "name": "xxxx",
    "num":"415"
  },
  "work":[
    {
      "monthYear":"01/2007",
      "workdate":"1|2|3|....|31",
      "workhours":"8|8|8....|8"
    },
    {
      "monthYear":"02/2007",
      "workdate":"1|2|3|....|31",
      "workhours":"8|8|8....|8"
    }
  ]
}
```

*I have to get the workdate, workhours from this json data.*

I am using Spark 2.1.1

I tried like this:

```
     val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("SQL-JSON").master("local[4]").getOrCreate()

     val df = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("sample22.json").values)
     // df.show()
     // df.printSchema()

    //val gatewayMessageContent = df.select("employeeDetails")
    //gatewayMessageContent.printSchema()
    val sensorMessagesContent = df.select("work")
    sensorMessagesContent.printSchema()

    // I am fallowing one article online, it showing like this, but it not working for me.
    val flattened = df.select(  $"root", explode($"work").as("work_flat"))
```

I am geting exception like this:

```
Error:(22, 31) value $ is not a member of StringContext
val flattened = df.select($"root", explode($"work").as("work_flat"))
                          ^
Error:(22, 48) value $ is not a member of StringContext
val flattened = df.select($"root", explode($"work").as("work_flat"))
                                           ^
```

In that example what he showed there is 'name' in top level. But my case I don't have any top element('work'). Because of that it not working.

I am new to Spark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use withColumn function of spark as

```
val flattened = df.withColumn("workDate", struct($"work.workdate"))
  .withColumn("workHours",  struct($"work.workhours"))
flattened.show(false)
```

You should have following output

```
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
|employeeDetails|work                                                                      |workDate                                    |workHours                               |
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
|[xxxx,415]     |[[01/2007,1|2|3|....|31,8|8|8....|8], [02/2007,1|2|3|....|31,8|8|8....|8]]|[WrappedArray(1|2|3|....|31, 1|2|3|....|31)]|[WrappedArray(8|8|8....|8, 8|8|8....|8)]|
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
```

I am assuming that you already have a dataframe with schema as

```
root
 |-- work: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- monthYear: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- workdate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- workhours: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Sorry to say but I am getting error like this  ----  `Error:(25, 54) value $ is not a member of StringContext
    val flattened = df.withColumn("workDate", struct($"work.workdate"))`
                                                     ^

Comment: @Sun How? It does not solve problems with implicits ;)

Comment: @T.Gawęda , Sun wanted to select workdate and workhours from work column,

Comment: Yes, but his error was with lack of implicits. Nevermind, the most important thing is that you or we helped author :)

Answer (score 2):

Import implicits:

```
import spark.implicits._
```

And now $ should work :)

It should look like:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("SQL-JSON").master("local[4]").getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

 val df = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("sample22.json").values)
```

Put it after creating SparkSession and before usage of any implicits, so many toDF functions, $, '